# God : Unable to start without sudo

Tags: linux, god

When I run god without sudo then god is not able to find event system . However when I run with sudo god able to find event system.

```
$ god -V
Version: 0.13.2
Polls: enabled
Events: none


$ sudo god -V
Version: 0.13.2
Polls: enabled
Events: netlink
```

about My M/c .. I'm using "Linux 3.2.0-38-virtual #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:37:47 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Please help me

Comment: So just run god with sudo. Is there a problem here?

Comment: Even god isn't able to find something.  Huh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [God website](http://godrb.com/):

*you need to sudo if you're using events on Linux or want to use the setuid/setgid functionality*

System event listening require root permissions, so `sudo` is required. Also, if you want `god` to spawn processes under different user ID from your own, `sudo` is equally required. This is the basic permission requirement in UNIX.